# json wont return using ajax (returns blank white page)

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, model-view-controller, controller

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s274C.png)

{"success":true,"message":"Scanned Device Type is not matched with system."}

return json keeps on returning data instead of following the code inside the ajax post method.

here's my ajax return code:

```
 function SubmitForm(form) {
        alert("grc");
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
        if ($(form).valid()) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: form.action,
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        alert(data.success);
                        //Popup.dialog('close');
                        //dataTable.ajax.reload();

                        //$.notify(data.message, {
                        //    globalPosition: "top center",
                        //    className: "success"
                        //})

                    }
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    }
```

i had the form have this code as well:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ScanTD", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { onsubmit = "return SubmitForm(this)" }))
{
```

while the return from the controller is this:

```
  return Json(new { success = true, message = result }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

the controller seems to be able to capture the result since the json returns it but not following the actions I've set inside the ajax. I tested adding the alert upon the trigger of the SubmitForm function and it is appearing but once it goes inside the controller, it doesnt trigger the alert inside the success code of ajax. it returns only the white page with the supposed success result.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what I did but I just added the resource for the jQuery validator and it seems to work now.